# Divide Multiple Columns by Multiple other Columns

Tags: python, pandas

For two dataframes:

```
 df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]}) 

 df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3], 'B': [4]})
```

How do I divide all values in df_1 columns A and B by the respective values of A and B in df_2 so that:

```
 df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.33, 0.66], 'B': [0.75, 1]})
```

I need to perform this operation over two large dataframes with the same headings. Please, scalable solutions.

Comment: `df_2` columns has only single value?

Comment: They do. Stackoverflow forces me to write more+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slicing of `df_2` as Series:

```
df_1.div(df_2.iloc[0])
```

Or:

```
df_1.div(df_2.squeeze())
```

Output:

```
          A     B
0  0.333333  0.75
1  0.666667  1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try

```py
df = df_1.div(pd.concat([df_2]*len(df_1), ignore_index=True)).round(2)
```

```
print(df)

      A     B
0  0.33  0.75
1  0.67  1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `df_3 = pd.DataFrame(df_1.values / df_2.values, columns=list(df_1.columns.values))`